# Upgrading JupyterLab in Jupyterhub

Tags: jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

I want to upgrade JupyterLab within JupyterHub. I've installed JupyterHub yesterday and noticed today, that the version of JupyterLab is `0.35.4`.

I tried to upgrade JupyterLab using the terminal in JupyterLab as well as standard ssh. The installed pip package is now `jupyterlab==1.0.4`. However, after a reboot JupyterLab still starts as version 0.35.4.

How can I upgrade the JupyterLab used by JupyterHub?

**Edit**: JupyterHub was installed using *The Littlest JupyterHub* on bare metal.

Comment: Found an unanswered git-issue: https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/issues/2656

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out it was my fault. I installed jupyterlab with `sudo -E pip3 install -U jupyterlab` from inside of jupyterlab.

However, you have to use: `sudo -E pip install -U jupyterlab` from inside of the jupyterlab.

**Edit**: I figured out `pip3` refers in my case to the local installation and `pip` to the installation of tljh - *The Littlest JupyterHub*.